# Collect data from text file/ ListBox and put clean data into another ListBox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

I have two list boxes. I have a text file that I have imported the raw data into a list box .

How can I extract certain data from what has been imported into the list box, and place the "clean data" into another list box?

So far all i seem to be able to get is the raw data into the 1st box and then nothing appears in the 2nd.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Public Structure FinalData
        Dim LocationString As String 'Location
        Dim TypeString As String 'Cities or Regions
        Dim StateString As String 'State
        Dim FemalesInteger As Integer 'How many females
        Dim MalesInteger As Integer 'How many males
        Dim FemalePercentageInteger As Integer 'Female percentage
        Dim MalePercentageInteger As Integer 'Male percentage
        Dim TotalInteger As Integer 'Total population

    End Structure
    Private Sub BrowseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BrowseButton.Click
        'Selects the file name for import
        Dim FileNameLocationString As String

        'establish initial settings
        OpenFileDialog.Title = "Please Select a File"
        OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
        OpenFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt*"

        'OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
        'First test to see if cancel has been selected
        If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            Exit Sub
        Else 'Selection has been made, save the file name to the text box
            FileNameLocationString = OpenFileDialog.FileName.ToString()
            If File.Exists(FileNameLocationString) Then
                FileNameLocationTextBox.Text = FileNameLocationString
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist")
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ImportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImportButton.Click
        Dim InRawDataStreamReader As StreamReader
        Dim RawDataLineString As String

        'Opens the file and imports data into list box
        Try
            'Check is file exists
            If File.Exists(FileNameLocationTextBox.Text) Then
                InRawDataStreamReader = New StreamReader(FileNameLocationTextBox.Text)

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Valid File")
            End If

            'Read Lines from the File and Add to the List Box
            Do Until InRawDataStreamReader.Peek = -1
                RawDataLineString = InRawDataStreamReader.ReadLine
                RawDataListBox.Items.Add(RawDataLineString)
            Loop
            InRawDataStreamReader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click
        'checks there is raw data loaded 
        If RawDataListBox.Items.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("No Data Has Been Loaded")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Splits the raw data into the structure
        Try
            Dim counterInteger As Integer = 1
            Dim FinalDataStructure(FinalDataListBox.Items.Count) As FinalData
            Dim CleanDataString As String

            While counterInteger < FinalDataListBox.Items.Count
                'reads one row into a string
                Dim FinalDataLineString As String = FinalDataListBox.Items(counterInteger).ToString
                'Splits string by comma
                Dim FinalDataArrayString As String() = FinalDataLineString.Split(","c)

                With FinalDataStructure(counterInteger)
                    .LocationString = FinalDataArrayString(0)
                    .TypeString = FinalDataArrayString(1)
                    .StateString = FinalDataArrayString(2)
                    .FemalesInteger = Integer.Parse(FinalDataArrayString(3))
                    .MalesInteger = Integer.Parse(FinalDataArrayString(4))
                    'calculate the percentages and totals
                    .TotalInteger = .FemalesInteger + .MalesInteger
                    .FemalePercentageInteger = .FemalesInteger + .TotalInteger
                    .MalePercentageInteger = .MalesInteger + .TotalInteger


                End With
                CleanDataString = "Location" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).LocationString + ","
                CleanDataString += "Type" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).TypeString + ","
                CleanDataString += "State" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).StateString + ","
                CleanDataString += "Females" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).FemalesInteger.ToString + ","
                CleanDataString += "Males" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).MalesInteger.ToString + ","
                CleanDataString += "Female Percentage" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).FemalePercentageInteger.ToString + ","
                CleanDataString += "Male Percentage" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).MalePercentageInteger.ToString + ","
                CleanDataString += "Total Population" + FinalDataStructure(counterInteger).TotalInteger.ToString + ","
                'Add to list box
                FinalDataListBox.Items.Add(CleanDataString)

                counterInteger += 1
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please post only relevant code.  If you can already successfully load the data into one `ListBox` then the code that does that is irrelevant and posting it just makes it harder for us to identify the issue.  As for your issue, you need to think about where the data is supposed to come from and check whether your code actually does that.

Comment: `Extract certain data`. What certain data?

Comment: @Malky.Kid
Within the text file there is a heap of data. here is an example:

Abbreviations:
ERP=Estimated Resident
A=Annual
LGA=Local Government Area
R=Region, Area, Shire, Town
C=City

LOCATION NAME,TYPE,STATE,MEASURE,LGA_2015,FEMALE,MALE,FREQUENCY,YEAR
"Albury","C","NSW","ERP",10050,26635,25087,"A",2015
"Armidale Dumaresq","R","NSW","ERP",10110,13245,12073,"A",2015


When I import the raw data into the first Listbox, I then need to extract only, the Location, Type, State, # of Males, # of Females, then the percentage of both and the total. (Sorry about the formatting)

Comment: Is the new data in the 2nd listbox based on what the user has selected on the first? If so you have to parse your string based on a delimiter. See https://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Comment: @Malky.Kid The user only gets to select the raw data that is imported into the first listbox. Once that data is imported, there is a load button for the second list box that will take the required information from the first listbox and put only the necessary information into the second, i.e the location, state, total population.

Comment: @Malky.Kid Yes thats exactly right. I'm not sure what i've done with my code that it doesn't display in the second listbox though.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are trying to do now when I read your code.  let me get back to you later

Comment: @Malky.Kid Thanks so much, that would be very much appreciated. i've been pulling my hair our for hours now! Thanks again!